# How to use IBM MobileFirst java adapter to update existing entity?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jax-rs, mobilefirst-adapters

The jax-rs resource method can get JSON which is part of document.
My issue is that I have to update existing object (entity). So I decided on creating jax-rs ContainerRequestFilter. This filter has to get existing object, replace its properties with new one and put it back to stream. Therefore I hope that I get entity completely in my resource method.
At first I has to get data for authenticated user. But 'securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser()' returns partially provided JSON data?

Is there any possibility to get authenticated user data in jax-rs filter (on ibm MobileFirst platform)?

There is the code of my filter:

```
@Provider
//@ManagedBean
public class UpdateFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
//ReaderInterceptor {

//@Inject
//ExistingObjectDao existingObjectDao;

@Context
AdapterSecurityContext securityContext;

@Override
@OAuthSecurity(scope = "protected") //doesn't work
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
    //context.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal() // is null
    AuthenticatedUser user = securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser(); //is null
    Map<String, String> authParams = (Map<String, String>) user.getAttributes().get("lotusCredentials");
    InputStream inputStream = context.getEntityStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    inputStream.read(bytes);
    String responseContent = new String(bytes);
    String id = context.getUriInfo().getPathParameters().getFirst("id");
    Object existingObject = null;
    try {
        existingObject  = existingObjectDao.get(id, authParams);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (existingObject != null) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectReader reader = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(existingObject );
        JsonNode r = reader.readTree(responseContent);
        responseContent = objectMapper.writer().writeValueAsString(r);
    }
    context.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(responseContent.getBytes()));

} 
}
```

Comment: If securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser() is null, this means something is wrong with the mapping. Is the scope mapped to a proper securitycheck and is the challenge handling complete? Do you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: Hi, yes. the scope is mapped to a proper securitycheck. It works good if I call resource method without this jax-rs ContainerRequestFilter. My resource method is annotated with  @OAuthSecurity(scope = "protected"). 
But as I understood mobile first doesn't allow to use @OAuthSecurity in Provider (filter and interceptors)